# Jsp : javascript undefined error and Unexpected identifier?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

My code as follows:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="kiben" content="no-cache">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var obj = "${sessionScope.selections}";
    function fillChecklist(){

        var selections={name:"feng"};
            selections = obj;
            var name=selections.name;
            var name2=name;     
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type=button onclick='fillChecklist()'>click</button>

</body>
</html>
```

When I open the page ,there are two errors(I don't click the button):

1):Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

2):Uncaught ReferenceError: fillChecklist is not defined

I checked many times, I still don't understand what wrong with my code?

I can get the data from session, this is the screen shot:
[image]

Comment: You'll have to look at the code as delivered to the browser. Probably what's happening is that JSTL expression is expanding to some text that includes a double-quote character. You should probably use a JSON encoder instead of just dropping it straight into your JavaScript code like that.

Comment: Updated my answer. This should work for you. Don't forget to mark the answer as good if it is

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript looks good. Maybe something with your `obj` variable.

Assuming you expect an object for `obj` and `sessionScope.selection` is a valuable JSON object :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var obj = JSON.parse('<%=sessionScope.selections%>');
    function fillChecklist(){
        var selections={name:"feng"};
            selections = obj;
        var name=selections.name;
        var name2=name;     
    }
</script>
```

Or if you want to use plain Javascript (like in your screenshot) :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var obj = JSON.parse(' // Use single quote, if you have a valid JSON, everything will be OK (assuming you escaped every single quote)
      {
        "something" : "blabla",
        "integer" : 4
      }
    ');
    function fillChecklist(){
        var selections={name:"feng"};
            selections = obj;
        var name=selections.name;
        var name2=name;     
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The javascript that you can see in the screenshot does look anything but good.